# Datagrid textbox search C#

Tags: sql, database, search, datagridview, textbox

I'm working on an Application for school and i have a datagrid connected to a local SQL database.

With the click of a button my data appears in the data grid, This all goes well.

The problem is that I want to be able to search specific customer ID's.

I'm fairly new to programming. I have googled for some hours but i can't find a good way to use most codes.

Does anyone know a simple way to add a filter on a textbox wich will then corrensponds with my DataGridView?

Comment: what programming language do you use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will give you the gridview row index for the value:

```
String searchValue = "somestring";
int rowIndex = -1;
foreach(DataGridViewRow row in DataGridView1.Rows)
{
    if(row.Cells[1].Value.ToString().Equals(searchValue))
    {
        rowIndex = row.Index;
        break;
    }
}
```

Or a LINQ query

```
    int rowIndex = -1;

    DataGridViewRow row = dgv.Rows
        .Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
        .Where(r => r.Cells["SystemId"].Value.ToString().Equals(searchValue))
        .First();

    rowIndex = row.Index;
```

then you can do:

```
 dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Selected = true;
```

Comment: This is for an ASP app i see. I'm Working on a Windows form. 
So these codes are all new for me :O :(

Comment: Take a look at the edit. This will select (Highlight) the row you are looking for.